# JS function does not respond to event onclick

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I have a a  problem I think is a easy one but I don't find the problem. I have a "menu" where I want to send a data to another page when I click one button. So I write a function in js to open a new tab and the send the data. But when I do click, it is like if the function doesn't exist.

```
<div id="botones">
    &nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <input type="button" value="<?=L::misc_export?>" onclick="javascript:pasarDatosParaExportar();" name="boton" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function pasarDatosParaExportar() {
    window.open('calculos.exportar.php?fecha2='+'<?=$_POST['fecha2']?>'+'&hasta='<?=$_POST['hasta']?>'&cuartel='<?=(int)$_GET['cuartel']?>'','_blank');
}
</script>
```

Comment: The `onclick` attribute's value should be JavaScript code.  Get rid of the `javascript:` there, that's not needed.

Comment: are you sure your string is getting populated correctly within `window.open(...` -- could be causing error. did you check the console?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `javascript:` from content of your "onclick". It's for `<a href="[HERE PUT javascript:]"`

If you have link and want to put JS code into "href" parameter, should use it:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('success!')">click</a>
```

But you can do the same like this:

```
<a onclick="alert('success!')">click</a>
```

Comment: While this is better practice, it does not prevent the event from firing, so this is not an answer.  It would be better suited as a comment on the original question.  https://jsfiddle.net/34a8wvuh/

Comment: Better practice is putting it aside from HTML code. For example: `document.getElementById('id').onclick = function() { /* body */ }`. But you'r right of course - putting it in "href" wont fire link. But you can also put "return false;" in end of "onclick" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the string delimiter characters (') in the parameter to the open function. I guess you probably mean to write something like this

```
function pasarDatosParaExportar() {
window.open('calculos.exportar.php?fecha2='+'<?=$_POST['fecha2']?>'+'&hasta=<?=$_POST['hasta']?>&cuartel=<?=(int)$_GET['cuartel']?>','_blank');
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem perhaps you should mark it as "accepted answer".

Answer (score 0):

Write the JavaScript code to define the function before its use in the `div` and above in code because html assumes that this code doesn't exists if it doesn't occur before its use. So just replace the `div` and `script` with each other. This should work fine. And there is no need to use `javascript:` before name of function. yo can use `onclick="pasarDatosParaExportar();"`.